# Calculate the long-term probability

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

The following question is an interview question about probability:

> There is a list of items and how many times each item is purchased
> (range from 10 to 100,000 times). The probability of users buying each
> item is uniform (same across all users). Let's say we have an item "A"
> that has been recommended ten times and purchased ten times. What is
> the long-term probability of being purchased for this item?

And the sample answer to the question is as follows:

> The probability of item A being purchased is not affected by the
> number of times it has been recommended.
>
> Since the probability of buying each item is uniform across all users,
> the long-term probability of item A being purchased is simply the
> proportion of times it has been purchased relative to the total number
> of purchases.
>
> For example, if item A was purchased ten times and there were 100
> purchases in the past, then the long-term probability of item A being
> purchased would be 10/100 or 0.1. However, it's important to note that
> this assumes that the probability of purchasing each item remains
> constant over time, which may not be the case in reality.

Is that not just a wrong answer because the probability of item A being purchased will be affected by the number of times it is recommended?

Comment: I read it a couple of times, and I find it quite unclear. It might be that the independency from recommendations is inferred from the uniform preference across users. If recommendations had an effect, you would expect differences across users (assuming they get different recommendations, or none)

Comment: I can't make any sense of the question, because the sense in which it uses "probability" is vague and appears to contradict the information given.  The meaning of "uniform across all users" is not even clarified by the sample answer.  I would have to guess, very tentatively, that the asker means the probability *distribution* of purchases is the same for every purchaser.  In interviews, you are best off pushing back against badly formed questions by (politely and tactfully) explaining where the ambiguities and errors are and asking for clarification, rather than guessing at the intent.